# website overlapping issue

Tags: css

I have a website and am a little bit stumped right now.

If you view the website at:

http://www.christornero.com

If you change the size of the window you will notice the right side bar "#nav2" overlaps the content area if the window size is changed, or if you view the website on smaller screens.

Anyway to change this to where the right side bar stays on the right side of the page without overlapping issues?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would take a look at [liquid website design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a horizontal scroll bar when the user has a smaller screen or window:

```
body { min-width: 1260px; position: relative; }
```

*Why I didn't use 1280? Because some browsers always show a scroll bar, and some users on a 1280 width screen don't have the window maximized*

If you want a better solution, I'd recommend a redesign. Some designs just don't scale well, and that includes yours.

**Update**
For this to work you're also going to need `position: relative;` because of the absolute positioning of the side bars. Also: note that this will only fix the overlapping, not the case where the site acts strange when you have a 2560x1440 screen. For that I really recommend learning CSS.

Comment: That doesn't fix it on my 1024 x 600 netbook.  I think the absolute positioning is part of the problem.

Comment: Are all browser scrollbars `20px`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish No but those which don't use one won't be affected much and those who are will at least show it properly.

Answer (score 1):

All of your DIV's on the page are positioned "absolute", hence they are taking position With respect to the window border.

I dont see any direct one line fix, you need to change bit of a code inside your markup.

inside your `#container` first write the #navigation then `#content` and then `#nav2`. and then position then using CSS, but "relative", along with `float`